# How to Compute Hours, Rate, Pay, When i compile i am getting error with Operations signs. please let me know how to i compute them

Tags: java

When i compile it, I am getting Error, something wrong with the Operation signs, in the line code error:

```
Pay = (40 * Rate) + (( Hours - 40) * (1.5 * Rate));
```

and below is the full code i used it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Staff {
    private int Hours;
    private int Rate;
    private int Pay;

    public Staff() {
        Hours = 0;
        Rate = 0;
        Pay = 0;
    }

    public void GetEmployee() {
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println(" Please Enter Hours");
        Hours = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
        System.out.println(" Please Enter Rate");
        Rate = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
    }

    public void ShowEmployee() {
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println(" Pays = " + Pay);
    }

    public void ComputePay() {
        if (Hours > 40) {
            Pay = (40 * Rate) + ((Hours - 40) * (1.5 * Rate));
        } else {
            Pay = (Hours * Rate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get a compile error, show it. If you get a runtime exception, show the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 1.5 is a double, not an integer.  The pay variable has to be type double:

```
package cruft;

/**
 * Staff
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465427/how-to-compute-hours-rate-pay-when-i-compile-i-am-getting-error-with-operatio
 * @since 12/13/2014 8:27 PM
 */

import java.io.Console;

public class Staff {
    private int hours;
    private int rate;
    private double pay;

    public Staff() {
        hours = 0;
        rate = 0;
        pay = 0;
    }

    public void getEmployee() {
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println(" Please Enter hours");
        hours = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
        System.out.println(" Please Enter rate");
        rate = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
    }

    public void showEmployee() {
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println(" Pays = " + pay);
    }

    public void computePay() {
        if (hours > 40) {
            pay = (40 * rate) + ((hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate));
        } else {
            pay = (hours * rate);
        }
    }
}
```

Learn and follow the Java coding standards.

Magic numbers are bad.  Your code obviously says "time and a half for more than forty hours", but it's better to use variable names to make that clear.

What if somebody works less than 40 hours?  Do they get paid less?

You have a bad abstraction here.  I would not have console input embedded inside an object.  What if you decide to use this app in a web app?  You have to rewrite, because there's no console.

I think of Staff as a collection of Employee.  Isn't this better named Employee?

showEmployee()?  Better to write a toString() method.

Comment: If somebody works less than 40 hours, he get paid regular" Pay = Hours * Rate);

Comment: If somebody works less than 40 hours, he get paid regular" Pay = Hours * Rate); Actually this is a subclass, and i will add more codes on it...thats why i named ShowEmployee();

Answer (score 1):

//Add cast to 'int'

```
Pay = (int) ((40 * Rate) + ((Hours - 40) * (1.5 * Rate)));
```